# Get Value from dynamic checkbuttons?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm building a GUI where i have first dynamic created checkbuttons:

```
for i in range(7,spaltendf):
    
    globals()['i_{}'.format(i)] = IntVar()
    
    globals()['Check_{}'.format(i)] = Checkbutton(root,text=df [i][zeilendf], variable = 'i_{}'.format(i)).grid(row = r, column =4)
    #print('i_{}'.format(i))
    
    r = r +1
```

Now the User can "check" the buttons and i want implement the answer in a database (When checked than 1, when not checked 0)

But when I try my code it gives me only 0 as answer even though i checked the button. Can somebody help me ?

Here is my code:

```
def myClick():

    for z in range(7,spaltendf):
        globals()['Eingabe_{}'.format(z)]=int(globals()['i_{}'.format(z)].get())
        print(globals()['Eingabe_{}'.format(z)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the third line, inside the `CheckButton`, there's `variable = 'i_{}'.format(i)`.
This sets `variable` to a string, instead try using the same logic you used when you created the `IntVar`:
`variable = globals()['i_{}'.format(i)]`.